# How can I echo commands in a tcsh script?

Tags: debugging, echo, csh, tcsh

Yes. I know I shouldn't be using it for scripting. Yes. It is rubbish. I am indeed a fool.

Nevertheless.

I'd like to see the commands the script is executing, for debugging purposes. I think you get this effect with set -x or set -v in bash scripts.

So e.g., if the script were

```
#!/bin/tcsh

echo "Hello"
```

then when it ran, I'd see

```
echo "Hello"
Hello
```

Comment: what do you mean 'echo commands'? , you can echo any text with like `echo "heres a text string that also includes a unix command name -- tar`. Consider editing your question to show any inputs, desired output AND your general idea of how to accomplish the outputs. It is possible to write useful code in tcsh, but the reason people harp on it (and I know from experience), is that tcsh is more limited in its features, and thus more limited to the scale and complexity of solutions you can create. Good luck.

Comment: @John Lawrence Aspden Please share some examples as to what exactly u want.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Put:

`set echo`
and/or
`set verbose`

at the top of your script. That will print out everything that happens in your script and are equivalent to the bash `set -x` and `set -v` commands.

Comment: This is most appropriate, as this flag helps in debugging eda tool scripts

Answer (score 12):

Lets say your script name is tcsh_file
Lets assume this file includes shebang as well.

now run this command on terminal

> tcsh -x tcsh_file

this will print every line before executing it. it's basically an interactive mode of execution.

Is this what you needed?

Comment: There's also `-v` to print stuff after history substitution (albeit those hopefully do not occur in a script, but maybe accidentally!), and the capitalized versions `-X` and `-V` that switch on the respective behaviour _before_ source the default `.tcsh` scripts. I always use `-f` to suppress that sourcing just to eliminate side effects of sourcing those multiple times. All from the man page.