# tcsh equivalent of bash 'set -x'

Tags: bash, debugging, tcsh

As described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/16204/how-to-make-bash-scripts-print-out-every-command-before-it-executes), bash can use the `set -x` command to print evaluated lines of code from the script being executed. Is there an equivalent in tcsh?

Comment: See: [How can I echo commands in a tcsh script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9095175/3776858)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why that didn't show up in my searches

Comment: I used Google with "[site:stackoverflow.com tcsh debug](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+tcsh+debug)".