# How to debug a tcsh script and put the debugged output in a file?

Tags: shell, debugging, tcsh

I want to debug my tcsh script. Like in sh script if we add set command with -x then it prints the execution of script.

```
#! /bin/sh
set -x
exec 2>/usr/bin/error.log
#My script code
```

And I tried this as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095175/how-can-i-echo-commands-in-a-tcsh-script) . But still don't know how to print in a file? I am writing below code:

```
#! /bin/tcsh
set echo
exex 2>/usr/bin/error.log
```

I am getting permission denied error.I have also tried running as root still same error. But that can be the error in my script. So I want to check in `error.log` where does the error occur. But after I run script the `error.log` file is not getting generated. Is there any other way to write `stderror` for tcsh? Can we use `exec` command in tcsh?
Also are tcsh and csh both same things or different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I echo commands in a tcsh script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095175/how-can-i-echo-commands-in-a-tcsh-script)

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh) explains the differences between tcsh and csh. ([Friends don't let friends write scripts](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) in either)