# "Set echo" doesn't seem to show code in tcsh script

Tags: shell, debugging, csh, tcsh

Please nothing in the realms of "Why are you using TCSH?". I have my reasons.

I'm trying to debug a tcsh script, but using the options "set echo" and "set verbose" don't actually seem to show the code that I'm trying to debug.

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9095175/how-can-i-echo-commands-in-a-tcsh-script), I tried "set echo" and "set verbose" in tcsh. I then ran this script 'test.tcsh':

```
echo "Hello world"
foo=1
bar=2
foobar=$(expr $foo + $bar)
echo $foobar
```

It returns the following output:

```
test.tcsh
test.tcsh
Hello world
3
history -S
history -M
```

So it shows clearly the output of the code. However, what I want to see is the code itself - the `echo`, the call to `expr` and so on. In bash, `set -xv` would do what I want, but it's seemingly not working here.

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: Could provide tcsh version with `tcsh --version` ? The `foo` and `bar` assignations don't seem to be tcsh syntax, it should be `set foo=1` and `set bar=2`. The foobar assignation should also be `set foobar=`expr $foo + $bar`` in tcsh. It seems to me that your script is run by bash or dash shell and not tcsh.

Comment: Note also that the set options `verbose` and `echo` are not inherited by the subprocess, you would need to include these commands in the shell script when you're calling it.

Comment: Sure, the version is `tcsh 6.18.01 (Astron) 2012-02-14 (x86_64-unknown-linux)`. And thank you - I'd clearly inherited bash syntax and forgot how to do tcsh scripting. Your solution now works :).

Comment: @Petesh - Is there an alternative to including the commands in the script? I would want to be able to easily change whether or not I'm debugging from the command line without modifying the file each time

Comment: @Lou: You mean: Propagating it to the child processes of your script? One (admittedly not very elegant) trick is to test at the start of each of your scripts, whether a certain environment variable, say: `ECHO`, is set, and has a certain value, say _yes_. If this is the case, you do a `set echo` in tcsh and a `set -x` in bash. By runnin a script with `ECHO` set to this value, all subshells invoked from the script you are running, which adhere to this convention, turn on tracing. It works even across bash/csh borders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure your script is run by the tcsh shell and to get it showing the code, simply add the following line as the first line of your script :

`#!/bin/tcsh -v`

This will make your script run by tcsh shell and set the tcsh shell to echo each script commands.

For reference, your actual script in the question doesn't seem to be a tcsh script, see comment under your question.

**EDIT:** To debug without altering the script, you can also simply launch the tcsh shell with the -v parameter followed by the script filename :

```
$ /bin/tcsh -v test.tcsh
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work! Is there any reliable way to change the debug mode without changing the shebang? I had thought that this is what `set echo` and `set verbose` would do, but when I include a shebang `#!/bin/tcsh` it doesn't produce any debug output, even after running both commands.

Comment: @Lou, yes. You can simply do `/bin/tcsh -v test.tcsh` from command line. I'll add that to the answer.